# Modifying a string in a list using a for loop?

Tags: python

Here is the code I wrote:

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
     """prints the names of magicians"""
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)

def make_great(magicians):
    """adds the word great to the string"""
    for magician in magicians:
        magician = magician + " the great"

list_of_magicians = ["Omen", "Carla", "David"]

greats = make_great(list_of_magicians)

print(greats)
```

the result I get from the program when ran from a terminal is the word "None". Please tell me the problem with my code.

and instead of using `print(greats)`, using `show_magicians(greats)` gives me the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-myname-\Documents\python_workspace\functions6.py", line 18,    
  in <module>
    show_magicians(greats)
  File "C:\Users\-myname-\Documents\python_workspace\functions6.py", line 5,
  in show_magicians
     for magician in magicians:
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Please give me advice and thoroughly explain what you did to fix the code.

Comment: You're not returning anything from `make_great`.

Comment: Oh thank you! But now that I added `return magician.title()` under the for loop in `make_great`,  the code only returns one string which is "Omen The Great". How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are only changing a copy of the string (for loops create a copy of each element in the list).
2. Your function isn't returning anything

You need to do something like this (modify in place):

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)

def make_great(magicians):
    for i in range(len(magicians)):
        magicians[i] += " the great"

list_of_magicians = ["Omen", "Carla", "David"]

make_great(list_of_magicians)

print(list_of_magicians)
```

or like this (return copy):

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)

def make_great(magicians):
    greats = []
    for magician in magicians:
        greats.append(magician + " the great")

    return greats

list_of_magicians = ["Omen", "Carla", "David"]

greats = make_great(list_of_magicians)

print(greats)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is twofold:

```
magician = magician + " the great"
```

does assign the name magician to a new string inside the body of your loop, but then does nothing with the string. You are not modifying the list your are iterating over.

The second problem is that `make_great` does not return anything, so it returns `None` by default.

Here's the fix:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    return [m + " the great" for m in magicians]
```

This uses a list comprehension, another way to write it would be

```
def make_great(magicians):
    result = []
    for m in magicians:
        result.append(m + " the great")
    return result
```

Notice that we are actually doing something with the new strings we create and that we return the result in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you'd need to instantiate another array in the `make_great` method and `return` the new array.

```
def make_great(magicians):
    """adds the word great to the string"""
    great_magicians = []
    for magician in magicians:
        magician = magician + " the great"
        great_magicians.append(magician)
    return great_magicians
```